# VS2017 RTM Painfully Slow While Typing Typescript Imports/Exports

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As the title suggests, I'm looking for help on what features/extensions I might look to disable in order to resolve a specific issue with the Visual Studio 2017 IDE (Windows).

When I'm working in Typescript the following will cause a node.js process to spike CPU usage and make the IDE lock up for several seconds with each keystroke.  It happens when filling in the paths for import and export statements, e.g.:

```js
import { foo } from 'app/file/bar';
export { foo } from 'app/file/bar';
```

Once I start typing `'app/file/bar'` everything goes to hell.  Windows resource monitor shows Node.exe spiking to almost 100% cpu. Its almost like it is scanning my entire project with each keystroke so that it can try and suggest auto-complete options (but nothing ever shows up, everything just chokes).

I've made sure my `tsconfig` excludes `node_modules`.

Please help - I have so much work to get done!

Comment: willing to paypal $25.00 for a solution.

Comment: I've created a short video outlining the problem... still an issue. 

https://ilos.video/rKYMPD

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Typescript 2.4.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258) which was released 2 days ago.

[This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15261) commit to the Typescript repository indicated that it would optimise the module resolution process, which should affect performance when modifying imports.  After installing it I have found the performance to be much better.

I had the same issue as you (~20-30 second lag when modifying imports) but now the lag is minimal.